# Did Benjamin Netanyahu say this about Christian Zionists?

Tags: quotes, israel, benjamin-netanyahu

The following quote is attributed to Benjamin Netanyahu, the current Prime Minister of Israel.

[image: My opinion of Christian Zionists ... Netanyahu]

It appears in [inspiringquotes.us](http://www.inspiringquotes.us/quotes/7kIB_4CbQIeuh).

It was shared by a couple of [Facebook](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Afacebook.com%20my%20opinion%20of%20christion%20zionists&oq=site%3Afacebook.com%20my%20opinion%20of%20christion%20zionists&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=site:facebook.com%20%22my%20opinion%20of%20christian%20zionists%22&start=10) users, and the quote or part of the quote appears in many neo-Nazi sites such as (Warning: racist content) [this](http://www.whale.to/b/netanyahu_h.html), [this](http://www.youngagain.org/economic92012.html), [this](https://web.facebook.com/max.igan.1/posts/739837572744217?_rdr), [this](http://zionistreport.com/2016/07/commentary-us-land-of-false-prophets-jew-lovers-christ-mockers-liars-and-war-mongers/) and in [this video cover](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9E1FEIYLwnI).

Did he say this about Christian Zionists?

Comment: Meme generators aren't notable claims

Comment: Please notice that the quote is about Christian Zionists, not about Christians.

Comment: Can you post a link to where you've seen this claim? As it stands, this is not notable.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I have added lots of links.

Comment: @Pere I updated the post. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I'm afraid the added links don't help the post. While popular social media posts have been used to demonstrate notability (in the sense that the claim is/may be widely believed), the one Facebook link that was added has 81 likes and 30 shares — hardly popular. The other four do repeat the claim, but there's no indication that they are widely read or believed (and they are nuts, which doesn't help notability).

Comment: The links you posted don't really show notability as they are literally random sites. Google autocomplete does not prove anything. Where does the image come from?

Comment: The quote appears for the first time on the Internet on February 1, 2001. (See [this Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?tbm=#tbs=cdr:1%2Ccd_min:1%2F31%2F2001%2Ccd_max:2%2F1%2F2001&q=%22My+opinion+of+christian+zionists%22) which is limited to that one day.) On that day, it suddently appears on these sites - whale.to, whitewraithe.wordpress.com, quoteaddicts.com, theaussiedigger.com, likesuccess.com, diggerfortruth.wordpress.com - as part of a collection of quotes (not part of a story or anything). Draw what conclusions you will.

Comment: @ff524 I think all those 01 February 2001 dates are default fake dates those sites use, and this fake quote really appeared early 2015

Comment: @DavePhD Good point about possibly fake dates, although the quote appears on Facebook (which has more reliable dating) earlier than 2015: https://www.facebook.com/nagdeems/posts/193203527383392

Comment: @ff524 yes, that looks real

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin *many* types of question get downvoted easily and the only thing they all have in common is they're bad questions. [Counter example 1](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/16178/does-israel-have-nuclear-weapons) [counter example 2](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36529/has-israel-broken-over-60-un-resolutions) [Counter example 3](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/30625/did-early-hamas-receive-some-support-from-israel) (need I go on?)

Comment: @ff524 the quote was in this Christian chat forum 2 July 2010: http://christianchat.com/bible-discussion-forum/16702-bibi-christian-zionists.html and here 02 June 2009 http://northerntruthseeker.blogspot.com/2009/06/famous-quotes-of-chosen-ones.html

Comment: @Sklivvz This quote is, unfortunately, notable because it has entered the "inspiringquotes" database http://www.inspiringquotes.us/quotes/7kIB_4CbQIeuh .  Also, it is on at least 100 websites, but usually as a comment.

Comment: @Jamiec Two of your counters have two or more downvotes. The one that  doesn't have any downvotes is about a issue that can't be confirmed (does it make it a bad question?).

Comment: @Jamiec Did you notice the 10 downvotes I got after asking this? (They were reversed.)

Comment: @DavePhD inspiringquotes has [2k views a day](https://sitenum.com/inspiringquotes.us), and that's for the whole site! On Christian chat there's plenty of people already debunking the claim. Northerntruthseeker seems like an antisemite site of no relevance. My point is, it seems like a quote that's being disseminated by very few individuals, and has really no major traction.

Comment: The image is not even on azquotes.com as far as I can tell. This does not look like a claim at all.

Comment: @Sklivvz I think I understand.  We don't want to help further spread a more or less obviously fake quote, unless it's already spreading rampantly, in which case we would then try to show it is false.

Comment: @Sklivvz https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9E1FEIYLwnI has around 1200 views.

Comment: "The following quote attributed to Benjamin Netanyahu, the current Prime Minister of Israel, is widely shared on social media" <- this seems patently false

Comment: @Sklivvz I searched for the quote and saw a huge number of results from facebook which is why I used that term. I have updated it to make it more specific.

Comment: @Ilya Melamed you describe the links as NSFW. Do any of the links contain nudity, or just hate speech?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, just hate speech.

Answer (score 7):

If he did it would be completely out of character.  So the provenance is doubtful.  For example, he said recently about [Christian Zionists](http://www.jta.org/2016/09/08/news-opinion/israel-middle-east/netanyahu-thanks-christian-zionists-in-netherlands-for-support)

> “I wanted to call and show my deep appreciation, and we know we have no better friends on earth than you,” the Israeli leader said on speakerphone to the board of Christians for Israel, an international pro-Israel advocacy and charity organization based near Amsterdam whose 30 affiliates worldwide have hundreds of thousands of members.

Considering the alignment of [US Christian Zionists with Israel](https://www.opendemocracy.net/paul-rogers/christian-zionism-and-netanyahu's-speech) the above quote in your claim is almost certainly an anti-Semitic slur.

Comment: Indeed, especially given the posting history.

Comment: Unfortunately, the quote in this answer doesn't show anything; it in fact would be expected for someone who considers a certain person or group to be "useful idiots" ("[b]ut don't tell them that") to not call them idiots to their faces.

Comment: -1 This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin, what proof do you expect to see to show that he didn't say that?

Comment: Regardless of what proof might be expected, this answer doesn't provide any. It is purely theoretical and opinion-based.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard, you can't definitively prove a negative.  But you can provide evidence that would tend to contradict the "fact" in question.  This is a good example of such evidence.  I'll repeat Ilya's question: What proof do you expect to see to show that he didn't say that?